# GroupBy index and columns then transform selected Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a sample DF:

```
sample_df_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
sample_df_train["date"]= ["2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01",
                "2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02"]
sample_df_train["date"] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df_train["date"])
sample_df_train.set_index(sample_df_train["date"],inplace=True)
del sample_df_train["date"]
sample_df_train["A_cat"] = ["ind","sa","sa","sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","ind","sa"]
sample_df_train["B_cat"] = ["sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","sa","ind","sa","ind","sa"]
sample_df_train
```

OP:

```
            A   B   C   A_cat   B_cat
  date                  
2020-02-01  13  13  14  ind      sa
2020-02-01  3   2   10  sa       ind
2020-02-01  2   6   6   sa       ind
2020-02-01  11  6   8   sa       sa
2020-02-01  4   9   1   ind      sa
2020-02-02  3   3   18  ind      sa
2020-02-02  17  3   17  sa       ind
2020-02-02  1   5   17  sa       sa
2020-02-02  13  15  9   ind      ind
2020-02-02  12  16  19  sa       sa
```

I am trying to transform this DF based on 2 conditions:

```
1. GroupBy based on Index and some columns
2. Transform (add 100 to column value) selected columns in the DF based on the GroupBy op.
```

IPs:

```
group_by_cols = ['date', 'A_cat']  Be noted that "date' is index. 
selected_columns = ["A"]
```

Code:

```
sample_df_train[selected_columns] = sample_df_train.reset_index().groupby(group_by_cols)[selected_columns].apply(lambda x: x+100)
```

OP:

```
             A  B   C   A_cat   B_cat
 date                   
2020-02-01  NaN 17  11  ind     sa
2020-02-01  NaN 10  9   sa      ind
2020-02-01  NaN 2   11  sa      ind
2020-02-01  NaN 3   16  sa      sa
2020-02-01  NaN 7   3   ind     sa
2020-02-02  NaN 6   5   ind     sa
2020-02-02  NaN 19  3   sa      ind
2020-02-02  NaN 4   15  sa      sa
2020-02-02  NaN 11  8   ind     ind
2020-02-02  NaN 14  14  sa      sa
```

Expected OP:

```
The entire DF with 100 added to values in Column A.
```

I am not understanding why I am getting `NANs`. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you just `reset_index` when you do `groupby` , so the original df's `index` is different from the `groupby` result

```
sample_df_train= sample_df_train.reset_index()
sample_df_train[selected_columns] = sample_df_train.groupby(group_by_cols)[selected_columns].apply(lambda x: x+100)
```